# Java minmax algorithm returning null move and failing to correctly undo moves

Tags: java, algorithm, chess, minmax

Here is the code for my minmax algorithm:

```
private static void minmax(){
    Move move = max(4, true, null);
    //System.out.println(move);
    board.makeMove(move.getFromPoint(), move.getToPoint());
}

private static Move max(int depth, boolean player, Move passedMove){
    if(depth == 0) return passedMove.setScore(board.boardVal());
    Move max = new Move(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    for(int i = 0; i < board.getMoves(player).size(); i++){
        Move move = board.getMoves(player).get(i);
        board.makeMove(move.getFromPoint(), move.getToPoint());
        //System.out.println(board);
        Move scoreMove = min(depth - 1, !player, move);
        board.undo();
        if(scoreMove.getScore() > max.getScore()) max = new Move(move.getFromPoint(), move.getToPoint(), scoreMove.getScore());
    }
    return max;
}

private static Move min(int depth, boolean player, Move passedMove){
    if(depth == 0) return passedMove.setScore(-board.boardVal());
    Move min = new Move(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for(int i = 0; i < board.getMoves(player).size(); i++){
        Move move = board.getMoves(player).get(i);
        board.makeMove(move.getFromPoint(), move.getToPoint());
        //System.out.println(board);
        Move scoreMove = max(depth - 1, !player, move);
        board.undo();
        if(scoreMove.getScore() < min.getScore()) min = new Move(move.getFromPoint(), move.getToPoint(), scoreMove.getScore());
    }
    return min;
}
```

Move is an object that stores a from location, a to location, and a score associated with the board's value after making that move.  The line `Move move = max(4, true, null);` assigns a null value to "move" (I don't understand why) and after the methods are run it leaves the board in a strange state, it seems like the moves are not correctly being undone, but I have checked that functionality repeatedly.

Here is an example of running the code (after commenting out the `board.makeMove(move.getFromPoint(), move.getToPoint());` line to prevent a null pointer exception):

```
8 [R] [N] [B] [Q] [K] [B] [N] [R] 
7 [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] 
6 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
5 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
4 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
3 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
2 [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] 
1 [R] [N] [B] [Q] [K] [B] [N] [R] 
   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h

a2,a4
8 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
7 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
6 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [N] [ ] 
5 [ ] [ ] [N] [ ] [ ] [ ] [R] [K] 
4 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
3 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [B] [B] 
2 [ ] [P] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
1 [P] [ ] [R] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] 
   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
```

It leaves only the computer's pieces, removing all of the player's.

Move Class:

```
public class Move {
    private Point fromPoint;
    private Point toPoint;
    private int score;

    public Move(Point fromPoint, Point toPoint, int score){
        this.fromPoint = fromPoint;
        this.toPoint = toPoint;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public Move(Point fromPoint, Point toPoint){
        this(fromPoint, toPoint, 0);
    }

    public Move(int score){
        this(null, null, score);
    }

    public Point getFromPoint() {
        return fromPoint;
    }

    public Point getToPoint() {
        return toPoint;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public Move setScore(int score){
        this.score = score;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "(" + fromPoint.y + ", " + fromPoint.x + ")" + " (" + toPoint.y + ", " + toPoint.x + ") " + score;
    }
}
```

The Board Class is built on a Stack of 2D arrays, here are the move and undo methods:

```
public void makeMove(Point fromPoint, Point toPoint){
    Piece[][] boardNode = new Piece[board.peek().length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < boardNode.length; i++){ //this was changed
        boardNode[i] = board.peek()[i].clone();
    }
    boardNode[fromPoint.y][fromPoint.x].setPoint(toPoint);
    boardNode[toPoint.y][toPoint.x] = boardNode[fromPoint.y][fromPoint.x];
    boardNode[fromPoint.y][fromPoint.x] = null;
    board.push(boardNode);
}

public void undo(){
    board.pop();
}

public ArrayList<Move> getMoves(boolean color){
    ArrayList<Move> moves = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Piece[] row : board.peek()){
        for(Piece piece : row){
            if(piece != null) {
                for (Point point : piece.moves()) {
                    if (piece.getColor() == color && straightLine(piece.getPoint(), point) && (board.peek()[point.y][point.x] == null || board.peek()[point.y][point.x].getColor() != color)) moves.add(new Move(piece.getPoint(), point));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return moves;
}
```

I expect the program to return an optimal Move (the one that leads to the highest scoring board state) and to leave the board as it was before the minmax method was executed.  Neither of these are happening, the method returns null and the board is completely changed.

After changing the makeMove() method in the Board class to correctly copy the board I am now getting NullPointerExceptions in that method:

```
8 [R] [N] [B] [Q] [K] [B] [N] [R] 
7 [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] 
6 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
5 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
4 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
3 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
2 [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] 
1 [R] [N] [B] [Q] [K] [B] [N] [R] 
   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h

a2,a4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Board.makeMove(Board.java:45)
    at ChessMain.min(ChessMain.java:87)
    at ChessMain.max(ChessMain.java:75)
    at ChessMain.min(ChessMain.java:89)
    at ChessMain.max(ChessMain.java:75)
    at ChessMain.minmax(ChessMain.java:63)
    at ChessMain.play(ChessMain.java:58)
    at ChessMain.main(ChessMain.java:15)
```

...

```
public abstract class Piece {
    private boolean color;
    private Point getPoint;

    public Piece(int x, int y, boolean color){
        this.color = color;
        getPoint = new Point(x, y);
    }

    abstract int getValue();

    public String toString(){
        return "";
    }

    public void setPoint(Point point){
        this.getPoint = point;
    }

    public Point getPoint(){ return getPoint; }

    public boolean takable(Point point){ return containsPoint(moves(), point); }

    private static boolean containsPoint(ArrayList<Point> list, Point point){
        for(Point listPoint: list){
            if(listPoint.x == point.x && listPoint.y == point.y) return  true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    abstract ArrayList<Point> moves();

    public boolean getColor(){ return color; }
}
```

Here is an example of an Object that extends Piece:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bishop extends Piece{

    public Bishop(int x, int y, boolean color) {
        super(x, y, color);
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> moves(){
        ArrayList<Point> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<>();
        int x = 1;
        while(getPoint().x + x <= 7 && getPoint().y + x <= 7){
            possibleMoves.add(new Point(getPoint().x + x, getPoint().y + x));
            x++;
        }
        x = 1;
        while(getPoint().x - x >= 0 && getPoint().y + x <= 7){
            possibleMoves.add(new Point(getPoint().x - x, getPoint().y + x));
            x++;
        }
        x = 1;
        while(getPoint().x - x >= 0 && getPoint().y - x >= 0){
            possibleMoves.add(new Point(getPoint().x - x, getPoint().y - x));
            x++;
        }
        x = 1;
        while(getPoint().x + x <= 7 && getPoint().y - x >= 0){
            possibleMoves.add(new Point(getPoint().x + x, getPoint().y - x));
            x++;
        }
        return possibleMoves;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){ return "B"; }

    public int getValue(){ return 3;}
}
```

Let me know if more information would be helpful.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so you know that `max(...)` is assigning null so debug `max(...)` and see what is returning null. It could be `if(depth == 0) return passedMove.setScore(board.boardVal());` but I don't know the possible return values of `passedmove.setScore(...)` since I don't see that function..

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help properly, otherwise we're just making guesses.

Comment: I think my question is now Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable, please let me know if anything else would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue I can see:

```
public void makeMove(Point fromPoint, Point toPoint){
    Piece[][] boardNode = board.peek(); // WARNING!!!
    // Instead, make a copy of the previous board state
    // so  you don't change all board states when you want to change one.
    boardNode[fromPoint.y][fromPoint.x].setPoint(toPoint);
    boardNode[toPoint.y][toPoint.x] = boardNode[fromPoint.y][fromPoint.x];
    boardNode[fromPoint.y][fromPoint.x] = null;
    board.push(boardNode); // WARNING!!!
}
```

Your `board` is using the same reference on each level of the stack.

When you call `Piece[][] boardNode = board.peek(); ... board.push(boardNode);` you are really just using the same reference for all your board states and modifying one of them will modify the object which all of them reference.. which I assume is not what you want.

This could be the root of your problem, if there are more issues besides that then update your question.

---

Update:

It was all still an issue in cloning the 2D array of the board state. You cloned the arrays but not the `Piece`s in them, thus when you update the position of the piece it is updating for that object that all states of the board reference.

First, make Piece implement `Cloneable`

```
public abstract class Piece implements Cloneable {
    // ...
    @Override
    public abstract Piece clone();
```

Then make all child `Pieces` actually clone themselves, Eg `Pawn` does this:

```
@Override
public Pawn clone() {
    return new Pawn(getPoint.x, getPoint.y, color);
}
```

Then this to clone your 2D array:

```
public void makeMove(Point fromPoint, Point toPoint) {
    final Piece[][] prevBoard = board.peek();
    final int width = prevBoard.length;
    Piece[][] boardNode = new Piece[width][];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        final int height = prevBoard[i].length;
        boardNode[i] = new Piece[height];
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            Piece p = prevBoard[i][j];
            if (p == null) {
                boardNode[i][j] = null;
            } else {
                boardNode[i][j] = p.clone();
            }
        }
    }
```

This seems to get you on the right track, but now it seems like the opponent is moving the players pieces, or something like that.

Best of luck with the rest!

Comment: Thanks for that, I made that change and am now getting NullPointerExceptions on this line `boardNode[fromPoint.y][fromPoint.x].setPoint(toPoint);`, I checked and it seems like it is copying the board correctly.

Comment: What is `board.getMoves(player)`, please include this function.

Comment: My guess is that there is no `Piece` at `board[y][x]` (it is `null`), the other possibility is that `fromPoint` or `toPoint` is `null`. You orient the board by `y` then `x`, you will need to make sure that this is the same orientation that `Move`s have when returned by `board.getMoves(player).get(i)`

Comment: I understand that, I just don't know why those would be null.  Added `board.getMoves(player)`.

Comment: please also include `Piece.getPoint()` and `Piece.getMoves()`

Comment: I just don't have enough of the program that I can run it and easily see why `boardNode[fromPoint.y][fromPoint.x]` is `null` maybe one of your `Piece.getPoint()` is pointing to a `null` spot on the board.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the help nonetheless, I'll make an update if I find anything.

Comment: If I had something I could run I could probably find the source of this issue pretty quickly. Perhaps drop the source somewhere? Anyway would you kindly accept this answer since I at least solved the first part of your problem? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to move this to chat, is there some way I can send you the project without posting it here?  I'm not super experienced with stack overflow.

Comment: You could stick em on a GoogleDrive and share the link perhaps

Comment: Edited my answer. Please like if you like.

Comment: Thank you!  I did like your answer but I have less than 15 rep so it's not visible, sorry.

Comment: My pleasure. glhf